# How to design the table for following use case?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I have two tables,  `widget` and `tier`. A company can be belong to any one tier (tier1, tier2, tier3) and every tier has some widgets enabled. For ex - tier1 has 3 distinct widgets enabled, tier 2 has 3 of its own distinct widgets and 3 widgets of tier1 also make total 6, tier3 in same way has total 9(3+3+3) widgets enabled.

`Company` table has a `tier_id` as a foreign key.

My widget and tier tables are described as below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`widget` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL,
 `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `tier_id` INT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `fk_widget_tier_idx` (`tier_id` ASC),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_widget_tier`
 FOREIGN KEY (`tier_id`)
 REFERENCES `mydb`.`tier` (`id`)
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tier` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL,
 `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Now lets say a company is of tier 3, how do I design the db in a way that when I fetch the values of widgets for tier3, it fetches me all 9 widgets? If I make a join of company with tier and then with widgets table I will get only 3 widgets which are included in tier 3. How to get the rest of 6 widgets (of tier 1 and tier 2).

I am using java + hibernate to deal with databases. Do I need to do this fetching manually in the code,  as in checking the level of tier and then creating a list of such widgets and returning it?

I hope the question is clear and not a very basic question(fear of downvotes).

Comment: Your join criteria should be a greater or less than rather than an equals.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well you have:

tear1 - > tear1_widgets

tear2 - > tear1_widgets + tear2_widgets

tear3 - > tear1_widgets + tear2_widgets + tear3_widgets

In your case i would follow an hierarchical model. I would keep the above hierarchy in a table in order to know every instance (in your case 'tear') from which instances inherit its properties (in your case 'widgets'). So every time you have an entry type 'tear3' you know that it must have 9 widgets and from where (tear1 and tear2 and tear3) you have to take them.

[image]

In the above sample you can see that you know from which table you can inherit your widgets, and you only have to write the query to bring them.

Plus with the particular design you can have instances (tears) with any compination of widgets you want.

*Added the image